# Disable the query retrieve (ctrl+f11) on a detail block in master-detail relation in Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracleforms

I have form, which has 3 datablocks. One of them is a master block and the other two are detail(child) blocks. When my cursor is in master block and I press (<kbd>F11</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) my form works fine, based on `emp_id` in master block.

But, when I go to detail block and press (<kbd>F11</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) it retrives the data for that block even though the `emp_id` in master-block is null.
So, I want to write a condition/trigger such that user will not be able to run a query on detail block when emp-id in master block is null. Which trigger should I use in the detail block to write this and how to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `Key-EXEQRY` on the detail record blocks.

```
begin
   << display your message>>
   raise form_trigger_failure;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write a trigger to do this.

You should have a Relation set up between the master block and each detail block. On each Relation, set the property **Prevent Masterless Operations** to False.